# How do I use CakePHP's model validation messages instead of the controller's setFlash messages?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

**Description**

I have a simple form on every page of my site - a single input and a submit button.  The point is just for the user to enter his/her email address and hit submit.

It works if the data is an email address - but if it's not a valid email address, it submits the form, the page reloads (or whatever), and the flash message comes up instead of my model's more specific "not a valid email" error.

**Question:**

So, how do I use the model's validation message instead of the controller's generic one?

**The form:**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Email', array('class'=>'form1', 'url'=>'/emails/add', 'inputDefaults'=>array('label'=>false))); 
echo $this->Form->input('Email.email');
echo $this->Form->end('SIGN-UP');
```

**The email controller "add" function (or method?):**

```
function add() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->Email->create();
        if ($this->Email->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email address has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email address could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            $this->set('error', 'custom error here');
            $this->redirect($this->referer());
        }
    }
}
```

**And the email model:**

```
class Email extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Email';

var $validate = array(
    'email'     => array(
        'is_valid'  => array( //named whatever we want
            'rule'      => 'notEmpty',
                'rule'      => array('email', true),
                'message'   => 'Please supply a valid email address.',
                'last'      => true //causes it to not check the next rule if this one fails
        ),
        'is_unique'     => array( //named whatever we want
            'rule'          => 'isUnique',
            'message'       => 'That email address is already in our database.'
        )
    ),
);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dave

CakePHP does this for you, you have set the validation correctly, the error is the REDIRECT if your save fails. This loses the post data and hence the validation messages

Simply

```
if ($this->Email->save($this->data)) {
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('The email address has been saved', true));
  $this->redirect($this->referer());
} else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('There were problems saving, please see the messages below.', true));                    
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't see this earlier.  

I don't think you've answered my question though - your code seems like it would just spit out "There was a problem saving..." instead of the error from the Model's validation, which is what I was asking.  Thank you for answering, and please let me know if I misunderstood your answer.

Comment: @Dave The problem is that you're redirecting even in the case of an error, which causes you to lose the error messages. If you **don't** redirect, the error messages will be injected into the form automatically (provided you're using the form helper properly). Validation messages don't persist across page refreshes.

Comment: ANSWER REWORDED (ty @Leo):  Cake puts the error from the Model validation in a .error-message div and will appear on the page UNLESS you did like I did in my question, and redirected the page even when it failed validation.

So - anyone who found this question - just don't redirect the page if it doesn't save.  Thanks both Leo and YOMorales - both answers worked great - just seems like this must have been the intended way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, you would use the $form helper's error options. See the [section of the manual on this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1401/options-error).

However, if you want to populate the flash message with the validation message, you can use the model method `invalidFields()`. Here is an example:

```
if (!$this->User->save($this->data)) {
    $validationErrors = $this->User->invalidFields();
    $this->Session->setFlash($validationErrors['email']); // named key of the rule
    $this->redirect('/somewhere');
}
```

What this does is to get the messages written in model for the validation rules that failed. While `invalidFields()` returns an array, you can manipulate the values within it to produce a better error message, like for example, concatenating the different error messages.

Btw, I noticed something bad in your code above. You are naming your model class as 'Email' and there is a core CakePHP class already named Email (which is the famous Email component), so I suggest you name the whole MVC for that differently.

Comment: Thank you!!  If you change is_unique to 'email' (the field, not the key), I'll mark it as the correct answer! TYVM!

Comment: Not trying to be rude but this is not the answer to your question

Comment: @Leo - you're not rude, but please explain?  Maybe I worded my question incorrectly?  Thanks to YOMorales's answer, I'm now using the error messages from my Model's validation instead of just typing in something in the controller.

Comment: @Leo - also, I apologize, I did not see your answer - will review it right now!  Thank you both for answering!

Comment: @YOMorales - thanks again for the answer, and also for the note at the bottom - I've changed it from Email and will refrain from using that again :)

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, had the field name wrong because I was writing that code from the top of my mind. But anyways, you can always `var_dump()` the result of `invalidFields()` and see exactly what is being returned. So, if you have any other issue that you cannot solve with the CakePHP Manual, then feel free to post here. Good luck. :)

Comment: @YOMorales - thanks again for your answer - it did work, but it turns out the answer above seemed to work with less code/implementation.  Your way helped me understand Cake a bit more too, so - again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to populate specifically the `setFlash` message with the model validation messages. As I posted earlier, you can display messages in another way by [following this](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1401/options-error). However, it is totally true that you won't get those messages if redirection occurs. At least now you know how to get the messages from the controller, in case you need it for other things. Btw, you are nice S.O. user.